# Java 8 DateTime API parsing date string when both pattern and value are unknown

Tags: java, date, time, java-8

I have a requirement to parse an unknown date time string using an also unknown but supplied date time format.  I want to parse to a `ZonedDateTime`. 
 If there is no zone contained in the pattern string, I want to assume UTC timezone.  The problem is, I'm not sure how to determine if the pattern string contains timezone information so that I can append `.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` when I create the `DateTimeFormatter`.  How should this be done?

```
String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"; // this will be unknown (could be any possible valid pattern)
String dateTimeValue = "2001-01-01 00:00:00 -0800"; // this will also be unknown

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat);
if(????) { // how to determine if the pattern contains timezone information
    dateTimeFormatter = dateTimeFormatter.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}

ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeValue, dateTimeFormatter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example formatting pattern is not correct for the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. For example uppercase `YYYY` means a week-based year, not likely the intention of the sender. The `DD` means day-of-year (1-366), again not likely the intention of the sender.

### `DateTimeFormatter` formatting codes

You will need to learn the codes being passed to you in such strings. Then you will need to translate to the proper formatting pattern codes used by the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

## `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

You will likely benefit from using the very flexible and powerful [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class where you can build up a format by multiple calls. After all the necessary calls, you finally generate a `DateTimeFormatter` by calling [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder::toFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#toFormatter()).

[Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20DateTimeFormatterBuilder%20java&t=h_&ia=web) for examples using this class.

## Other issues

> how to determine if the pattern string contains timezone information

The `Z` in the passed formatting code tells you.

> I can append .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)

If you are trying to adjust to UTC, do that *after* you have parsed the input string into a date-time object. To get to UTC, merely call `toInstant`, as an `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition.

> I'm not adjusting to UTC, I want to set the zone as UTC if there is no zone specified in the pattern.

If your input string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC, then parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

If you know for certain the string without zone/offset was indeed actually intended for a particular zone/offset, then:

- Apply an offset ([`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)) to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).
- Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

With a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), you now have a moment, a point in time.

What is the difference between zone and offset? An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more. A zone, in contrast, is *much* more. A zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123" ) ;  // *Not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline.
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ; // Assign an offset to determine a moment.
```

You seem to be overly focused on parsing as a way of applying your business logic. Instead, **make your parsing as simple and direct as possible** to get a java.time object matching the input. Only *after* parsing should you be making adjustments or transformations on your date-time value. Lastly separate both this parsing and transforming code from your other business logic work, so you have three distinct phases: (1) simply/directly parse, (2) adjust/transform value, (3) utilize date-time value for business purpose.

## ISO 8601

This project of yours is fraught with risks. Taking on responsibility for somebody else’s arbitrary string inputs with their own invented formatting codes is something I would simply refuse to do. The success or failure is out of your control, as you may never know completely what will arrive.

The wiser approach is to shift the burden to the source of this incoming data. They should be passing your strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That standard was devised for exactly this purpose, exchanging date-time values as text. The standard formats are cleverly designed to be unambiguous, and easy to parse by machine as well as easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard by appending name of the time zone in square brackets. I would advise the source of your data to do the same if sending a zoned value — generally best to exchange only UTC values.

Comment: I am familiar with the formatting codes, I did not proofread my example adequately.  The `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` looks promising.  I'm not adjusting to UTC, I want to set the zone as UTC if there is no zone specified in the pattern.  Looks like I can do that with `DateTimeFormatterBuilder::parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)`.  And yes, if it was up to me, I would accept only ISO8601 into the system.  However, it is not up to me so I need to determine a working solution to this problem.

Comment: @benw I added a section to the Answer about assigning an offset of zero (UTC itself) to an input string lacking any indicator of zone or offset. You seem to be overly focused on parsing as a way of applying your business logic. Instead, make your **parsing as simple and direct as possible** to get a *java.time* object matching the input. *After parsing*, make adjustments to transform your date-time value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `if` at all.  [As described in the java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-), the 'override zone' is only applied if no zone is found in the text.  (Which makes the choice of the word *override* somewhat odd, but it's from the perspective of formatting rather than parsing.)

You can just always set it and it will only be used when needed.

Also, incidentally `DateTimeFormatter` is an immutable class.  In your example the withZone would do nothing because you discarded the object it returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way to identify is if the given date is parsed using ZonedDateTime. If it can't be parsed, it doesn't have timezone information.

```
  DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat);

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = null;
    try{
      zonedDateTime  = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeValue, dateTimeFormatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
      // if can't parse to ZoneDateTime
      LocalDateTime dateTime  = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeValue, dateTimeFormatter);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using exceptions for flow control? Is there a variant of parse that can check a format as opposed to throwing?

Comment: would be a pattern matching and parsing and verifying, would be a lot of code.